# I need help in creating dynamic arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, inputbox

can someone help me in solving the following problem?
Basically I have to create a dynamic array using inputbox,which asks for a series of numbers 'til value is empty(you press enter or sth). Then I have to determine the average value and the sum.
Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Can you show us what you attempted?

Comment: Why do you need a "dynamic array" to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Why use an array for this? It gets messy and `ReDim` has a fairly high amount of overhead.

A simple loop can do this (note that validation is missing, but you get the idea):

```
Dim valuesEntered As Integer
Dim total As Integer

valuesEntered = 0
total = 0

Dim inputValue As String
Do
    inputValue = InputBox("Enter a number or leave empty to stop.")

    If inputValue <> "" Then
        valuesEntered = valuesEntered + 1
        total = total + CInt(inputValue)
    End If
Loop Until inputValue = ""

MsgBox "Total: " & total & " / Average: " & (CDbl(total) / CDbl(valuesEntered))
```

**However** if you *must* do this with an array, at least consider using a `Collection` instead as it is already a dynamic construct.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done e.g. by using `Application.InputBox` function and then `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average`, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum`.

Two examples of usage of `Application.InputBox`.

- With Type = 1 *(example with do-loop, this is probably what you asked for)*
- With Type = 64 *(here example how to insert all array values in one step)*

More infor about usage of `Application.InputBox` e.g. here:
http://codevba.com/excel/application_inputbox.htm#number *(Note: the link is for Excel so ignore it if this question is not about Excel).*

```
Option Explicit

Sub WithInputBoxType1()
    Dim value, values
    Dim averageValue As Double
    Dim sumValue As Double

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Do
        value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter number:", Type:=1)
        If value <> False Then
            If IsArray(values) Then
                ReDim Preserve values(UBound(values) + 1)
            Else
                ReDim values(0 To 0)
            End If
            values(UBound(values)) = value
        End If
    Loop While value

    If Not IsArray(values) Then _
        Exit Sub

    averageValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(values)
    sumValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(values)

    Debug.Print "average = '" & averageValue & "', sum = '" & sumValue & "'"

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub

Sub WithInputBoxType64()
    Dim values
    Dim averageValue As Double
    Dim sumValue As Double

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    values = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter {1;2;3} etc. including the curly braces.", Type:=64)

    If values = False Then _
        Exit Sub

    averageValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(values)
    sumValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(values)

    Debug.Print "average = '" & averageValue & "', sum = '" & sumValue & "'"

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub
```